# Infinite Sequence of Sets

Tags: probability-theory

> Let $S_1, S_2, \ldots$ be an infinite sequence of sets. Prove that
> $$
> \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} \bigcap_{n=k}^{\infty} S_n = \{x:x \in S_k, ~\text{for all but finitely many $k$} \}
> $$
> (hint: To prove that $S=T$, we need to show $S \subseteq T$ and $T \subseteq S$)
> Can someone help me answer the question with some explanation, Thank you!

Comment: As a minimum you're expected to explain what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let $x\in \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \bigcap_{k\geq n}S_k.$ Then, there is $n\in\mathbb N$ s.t. $x\in \bigcap_{k\geq n}S_k$, i.e. there is $n\in\mathbb N$ s.t. $x\in S_k$ for all $k\geq n$. In other word, $$x\in \{x\mid x\in S_k \text{for all but finitely many $k$}\}.$$

Conversely, if $$x\in\{x\mid x\in S_k \text{for all but finitely many $k$}\},$$
then there is $n\in\mathbb N$ s.t. $x\in S_k$ for all $k\geq n$, i.e. $$x\in \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \bigcap_{k\geq n}S_k.$$